# SQL Join on Table A value within Table B range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables that can be seen in accompanying image.

*Table A* contains **Department**, **Month** and **Average**.

*Table B* contains **Month**, **Year**, **RangeStart**, **RangeEnd** and **Colour**.

If you look at the screen shot of *Table B*, you will see for each Month you have a Green, Yellow, Orange and Red value. You also have a range.

**What I need.........**

I need a new column on *Table A* named 'Colour'. In this column, I need either Green, Yellow, Orange or Red. The deciding factor on which colour is assigned to the month will be the 'Average' column.

For example:

DepartmentA for May's Average is equal to `0.96`
Upon referencing *Table B*, I can see that line 8, `0.75+` will be the range this fits into. Therefore Red is the colour I want placed in *table A* next to Mays average.

I have left RangeEnd for the highest range per month as NULL as it is basically `75+`, anything greater than `0.75` slots in here.

Can anyone point me in the right direction that is not too time consuming.

[image]

Comment: Do you really need to *store* this value in a column in Table A? It's generally better not to store information that can be recomputed. Could you not just add this column to a *query* against these tables?

Comment: So you don't want to use subqueries?

Comment: isn't there a year in table A?

Comment: I can add Year to Table A, i just left it out to keep simple, Table A is actually a view.

Comment: I think the OP just wants the value of the new column to be calculated on the fly, not 'stored' as such.

Comment: @SelectDistinct i was just wondering, because it seems to be broken without year ;-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you can use it straight forward:

```
select *
from table a
    join table b
        on a.month = b.month
           and a.average between b.rangestart and isnull(b.rangeend,10000) -- 100000 = greater than max value
```

Answer (score 3):

So really you want

```
select a.*,b.colour from a 
left join table b on a.month=b.month 
 and ((b.rangeend is null and a.average>b.rangestart) 
    or (a.average between b.rangestart and b.rangeend))
```

Im not promising it works as I didnt have time to enter some tables and data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the new column to TableA and then update it with values from table B, this is the final UPDATE:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET Colour = B.Colour
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B ON B.Month = A.Month AND B.RangeStart < A.Average AND (B.RangeEnd IS NULL OR B.RangeEnd > A.Average)
```

You should use LEFT OUTER JOIN and provide a default value if it is possible that you don't have data in table B for a given month and average in table A.

```
UPDATE TableA
SET Colour = ISNULL(B.Colour, N'SomeColour')
FROM TableA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB B ON B.Month = A.Month AND B.RangeStart < A.Average AND (B.RangeEnd IS NULL OR B.RangeEnd > A.Average)
```

Besides, you should check whether your data in Table B depends on the year, as it seems to happen with table A.

In this case, you should add this field to the Join's On clause:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET Colour = B.Colour
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B ON B.Year = A.Year AND B.Month = A.Month AND B.RangeStart < A.Average AND (B.RangeEnd IS NULL OR B.RangeEnd > A.Average)
```

Before you run the update, you can check that you are getting the desired values by running this query first:

```
SELECT Department, A.Month, Average, B.Colour
FROM @tableA A
INNER JOIN @tableB B ON B.Month = A.Month AND B.RangeStart < A.Average AND (B.RangeEnd IS NULL OR B.RangeEnd > A.Average)
```

Hope this helps :)