# How to find the grade and student name from grade and student table

Tags: sql

I have a `Student` table with the below column

```
Student_id|Marks
9|90
1|37
```

And `Grade_discription` Table

```
Min_Score|Max_Score|Grade

0|30|c
31|60|B
61|90|A
```

I want the output

```
Student_id|Grade

1 |B
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Join on Table A value within Table B range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604146/sql-join-on-table-a-value-within-table-b-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select s.Student_id, g.Grade
  from Student s join Grade_discription g 
    on s.Marks between g.Min_Score and g.Max_Score
 order by s.Student_id;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Student_id|Grade

1 |B
9 |A
```