# How to get range values ​from other tables in access with Sql to datagridview in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, subquery

How to get range values ​​from other tables in access with SQL to DataGridView in VB.Net?

Is it possible to get a range of values ​​from the payroll decision table or I have to change the fields from the payroll decision table, please guide me.

Is there any other solution?

```vb
Public Sub jokenselect(ByVal sql As String)
    Try
        con.Open()
        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = sql
        End With

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    End Try
    con.Close()
    da.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub RetrieveData()
    jokenselect("
SELECT 
EC.EMPID
, E.NAME
, format(EC.SKILL/(select MIN(MINSKILL.SKILL) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCSKILL/100 from tblWeightingCriteria),'#,##0.00') as SKILL
, format(EC.EXPERIENCE/(select MIN(MINSKILL.EXPERIENCE) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCEXPERIENCE/100 from tblWeightingCriteria),'#,##0.00') as EXPERIENCE
, format(EC.APPEARANCE/(select MIN(MINSKILL.APPEARANCE) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCAPPEARANCE/100 from tblWeightingCriteria),'#,##0.00') as APPEARANCE
, format(EC.EDUCATION/(select MIN(MINSKILL.EDUCATION) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCEDUCATION/100 from tblWeightingCriteria),'#,##0.00') as EDUCATION
, format(EC.SKILL/(select MIN(MINSKILL.SKILL) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCSKILL/100 from tblWeightingCriteria)+EC.EXPERIENCE/(select MIN(MINSKILL.EXPERIENCE) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCEXPERIENCE/100 from tblWeightingCriteria)+EC.APPEARANCE/(select MIN(MINSKILL.APPEARANCE) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCAPPEARANCE/100 from tblWeightingCriteria)+EC.EDUCATION/(select MIN(MINSKILL.EDUCATION) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCEDUCATION/100 from tblWeightingCriteria),'#,##0.00') as TOTAL CPI 
FROM tblEmployeeCriteria EC 
INNER JOIN tblemployee E ON EC.EMPID = E.EMPID 
ORDER BY 7 DESC")
    filltable(DataGridView2, "EmpPic")
    lbltotalemployee.Text = DataGridView1.RowCount
End Sub
```

The result of the sql code that I posted

| NAME | SKILL | EXPERIENCE | APPEARANCE | EDUCATION | TOTAL CPI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST1 | 145.80 | 83.91 | 109.80 | 129.60 | 469.11 |
| TEST2 | 121.50 | 109.73 | 85.40 | 113.40 | 430.03 |

Payroll decision table (tblPayrollDecision)

| RANGECPI | RANGESALARY |
| --- | --- |
| 451-470 | 11000000 - 12000000 |
| 431-450 | 10000000 - 11000000 |
| 411-430 | 8000000 - 10000000 |

the desired sql code results but not updated with "RangeSalary" from tblPayrollDecision

```
 jokenselect("
SELECT
EC.EMPID
,E.[NAME]
,format(EC.SKILL/(select MIN(MINSKILL.SKILL) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCSKILL/100 from tblWeightingCriteria)+EC.EXPERIENCE/(select MIN(MINSKILL.EXPERIENCE) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCEXPERIENCE/100 from tblWeightingCriteria)+EC.APPEARANCE/(select MIN(MINSKILL.APPEARANCE) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCAPPEARANCE/100 from tblWeightingCriteria)+EC.EDUCATION/(select MIN(MINSKILL.EDUCATION) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCEDUCATION/100 from tblWeightingCriteria),'#,##0.00') as TOTAL
FROM tblEmployeeCriteria EC 
INNER JOIN tblemployee E ON EC.EMPID = E.EMPID
ORDER BY 3 DESC")
```

Desired Result

| NAME | TOTAL CPI | RANGESALARY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TEST1 | 469.11 | 11000000 - 12000000 |
| TEST2 | 430.03 | 10000000 - 11000000 |

According to the request from @june17, I provide raw data

tblemployee

| EMPID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 10037 | Tamendran |
| 10046 | Ponisan |
| 10049 | Sudio |

tblEmployeeCriteria

| EMPID | SKILL | EXPERIENCE | APPEARANCE | EDUCATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10037 | 90 | 65 | 90 | 80 |
| 10046 | 85 | 75 | 70 | 85 |
| 10049 | 75 | 85 | 70 | 70 |
| 10085 | 50 | 55 | 50 | 50 |

tblWeightingCriteria

| WCSKILL | WCEXPERIENCE | WCAPPEARANCE | WCEDUCATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 81 | 71 | 61 | 81 |

```
        jokenselect("
SELECT
EC.EMPID
,E.[NAME]
,format(EC.SKILL/(select MIN(MINSKILL.SKILL) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCSKILL/100 from tblWeightingCriteria)+EC.EXPERIENCE/(select MIN(MINSKILL.EXPERIENCE) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCEXPERIENCE/100 from tblWeightingCriteria)+EC.APPEARANCE/(select MIN(MINSKILL.APPEARANCE) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCAPPEARANCE/100 from tblWeightingCriteria)+EC.EDUCATION/(select MIN(MINSKILL.EDUCATION) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCEDUCATION/100 from tblWeightingCriteria),'#,##0.00') as [TOTAL CPI]
FROM tblEmployeeCriteria EC 
INNER JOIN tblemployee E ON EC.EMPID = E.EMPID
ORDER BY 3 DESC")
```

Results from the above query

| EMPID | NAME | TOTAL CPI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10037 | Tamendran | 469.11 |
| 10046 | Ponisan | 457.62 |
| 10049 | Sudio | 430.03 |

tblPayrollDecision

| RangeCPI | RangeSalary |
| --- | --- |
| 451-470 | 11.000.000 - 12.000.000 |
| 431-450 | 10.000.000 - 11.000.000 |
| 411-430 | 8.000..000 - 10.000.000 |

Desired result final

| EMPID | NAME | TOTAL CPI | RangeSalary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10037 | Tamendran | 469.11 | 11.000.000 - 12.000.000 |
| 10046 | Ponisan | 457.62 | 11.000.000 - 12.000.000 |
| 10049 | Sudio | 430.03 | 10.000.000 - 11.000.000 |

Comment: Clarify how the ORDER BY clause should work. What do you think it accomplishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object names with space must be enclosed in brackets ([ ]). So your original query should not work because of alias field name `TOTAL CPI` not using brackets. Advise not to use spaces in naming convention.

Complication because RANGECPI values are text strings, not numbers. If range limits were in separate fields, SQL could use [SQL Join on Table A value within Table B range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604146/sql-join-on-table-a-value-within-table-b-range), so you need to parse RANGECPI string to number values. Also, TotalCPI of 430.03 will not match any range because it falls between begin and end of ranges. Resolving this in query is another complication.

Pulling RangeSalary values into your original query would require repeating entire TotalCPI calculation in JOIN or WHERE clause. Use your query in another query:

```
SELECT EmpID, [Name], TotalCPI, RangeSalary FROM (your original query here) AS E 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Left(RangeCPI,3) AS Start, Mid(RangeCPI,5,3) + 1 AS End, RangeSalary 
     FROM tblPayrollDecision) AS PD
ON E.TotalCPI >= PD.Start AND E.TotalCPI < PD.End;
```

Be aware, cannot build/view this query in Design View - Access will reject the JOIN syntax in the graphical display.

Consider this modification of your original query:

```
SELECT EC.EMPID, E.NAME, 
Format([EC].[SKILL]/MinS*100*([WCSKILL]/100),'Standard') AS SKILL, 
Format([EC].[EXPERIENCE]/MinX*100*([WCEXPERIENCE]/100),'Standard') AS EXPERIENCE, 
Format([EC].[APPEARANCE]/MinA*100*([WCAPPEARANCE]/100),'Standard') AS APPEARANCE, 
Format([EC].[EDUCATION]/MinE*100*([WCEDUCATION]/100),'Standard') AS EDUCATION, 
Val([Skill])+Val([Experience])+Val([Appearance])+Val([Education]) AS TotalCPI
FROM
    (SELECT Min(Skill) AS MinS, Min(Experience) AS MinX, Min(Appearance) AS MinA, Min(Education) AS MinE 
     FROM tblEmployeeCriteria) AS MinData, 
tblWeightingCriteria, 
tblEmployeeCriteria AS EC INNER JOIN tblemployee AS E ON EC.EMPID = E.EMPID
ORDER BY 7 DESC;
```

Comment: thanks your answer, but how can I update and adapt  your sql answer code with my sql code post `the desired sql code results but not updated with "RangeSalary" from tblPayrollDecision` please guide me

Comment: Query produces desired output. You want to update a table with RangeSalary values? What table and what field? Your question does not show any attempt to update a field. Why commit to a table when value can be retrieved by query when needed?

Comment: `You want to update a table with RangeSalary values? What table and what field?`  I generate the value "Total" by calculating Select from another table whether it is possible to simultaneously get the value of "rangesalary"

Comment: `"SELECT EC.EMPID,E.[NAME],format(EC.SKILL/(select MIN(MINSKILL.SKILL) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCSKILL/100 from tblWeightingCriteria)+EC.EXPERIENCE/(select MIN(MINSKILL.EXPERIENCE) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCEXPERIENCE/100 from tblWeightingCriteria)+EC.APPEARANCE/(select MIN(MINSKILL.APPEARANCE) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCAPPEARANCE/100 from tblWeightingCriteria)+EC.EDUCATION/(select MIN(MINSKILL.EDUCATION) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCEDUCATION/100 from tblWeightingCriteria),'#,##0.00') as [TOTAL CPI]`

Comment: `FROM tblEmployeeCriteria EC
INNER JOIN tblemployee E ON EC.EMPID = E.EMPID
ORDER BY 3 DESC"` I use that SQL to generate "NAME" and "TOTAL CPI" How can I add one direct column which is "RangeSalary"

Comment: My answer worked with sample data provided which is result of query and produces desired result. Incorporating nested query from my answer into your original SQL would probably require repeating entire TotalCPI calculation in the JOIN ON clause. Sometimes queries must be built progressively and "all in one" statement is not practical. Provide sample raw data and I can explore further.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have updated the raw data example so that it can be guided by you

Comment: Thanks for your answer but example for the total CPI  `EMPID 10037` It should be the result 469.11 but your code result 325

Comment: Not when I run query. I get 469.11. I get the exact data shown in your desired results table.

Comment: I use my query with your query all the same results only total cpi is different

Comment: if I run the query in an access query then the total result is the same but if run your query in via OleDb vb.net the total cpi result does not match

Comment: I can't help you with VB.net. Build query in Access. Have VB.Net pull from that query object. Does that work?

Comment: I tried the desired result or I created it with the name query2 in Access already appeared the result but I called it on the vb.net there was an error `Ierrorinfo.getDescription failed with E_Fail(0x80004005)`

Comment: You have query that produces the desired output. Getting VB.net to pull the data is another issue. And I can't help with that. Probably should start another question.

Comment: Your efforts have yielded results in MS Access so I had to post with a different question